# Shiny eventReactive requiring two invalidations

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

There are many examples of Shiny apps with `eventReactive` with multiple inputs that responds when *either* of the inputs are invalidated. However, I'm trying to create an app with an `eventReactive` that runs when the app is only started, and only when both the Val1 `textInput` is updated and the `actionButton` is pressed. Below is a stripped-down version of my app.

I've tried the curly brackets, the `c()` approach, and `!is.null(input$Val) & !is.null(input$Run)` in the event portion, but all without success (for the latter - because I assume that an `inputText` is returning a non-NULL value is all cases, but I can't figure out what it returns when invalidated...).

Many thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    dat <- eventReactive(input$Val1, { 
            data.frame(x = input$Val1, y = 1)
            }, ignoreNULL=FALSE) 

    output$table <- renderTable({ 
        dat()
        })} 

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
                textInput(inputId = "Val1", label = "Val1", value = "5"),
                textInput(inputId = "Val2", label = "Val2", value = "51"),
                actionButton("Run", "Run", class = "btn-success")) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeader(), 
    sidebar = sidebar,
    body = dashboardBody(mainPanel(fluidRow(tableOutput("table")))))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you 1. want to only execute `eventReactive` when the action button is pressed regardless of the state of `Val1` or 2. do you want that the `eventReactive` is executed when the action button is pressed and `Val1` is different from the previous execution of `eventReactive`? Or something else?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I want the `eventReactive` to execute only when both the Val1 `textInput` is updated and the `actionButton` is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that compares the current value of `Val1` with the value of `Val1` at the last trigger of `eventReactive`. I don't do the comparison (and use `req` for it) directly in the `eventReactive` because then in the case it was triggered but `Val1` didn't change, `dat` wouldn't show anything (and also lose the last shown value).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  comparison_values <- reactiveValues(trigger_event = 0,
                                      previous_input = "value_on_startup")
  
  observeEvent(input$Run, {
    if (input$Val1 != comparison_values$previous_input) {
      comparison_values$trigger_event <- comparison_values$trigger_event + 1
      comparison_values$previous_input <- input$Val1
    }
  })
  
  dat <- eventReactive(comparison_values$trigger_event, {
    data.frame(x = input$Val1, y = 1)
  }, ignoreNULL=FALSE) 
  
  output$table <- renderTable({ 
    dat()
  })} 

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  textInput(inputId = "Val1", label = "Val1", value = "5"),
  textInput(inputId = "Val2", label = "Val2", value = "51"),
  actionButton("Run", "Run", class = "btn-success")) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeader(), 
                    sidebar = sidebar,
                    body = dashboardBody(mainPanel(fluidRow(tableOutput("table")))))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```